# Flutter nullable error when creating class parameterized constructor

Tags: flutter, null, nullable, non-nullable

I updated flutter stable version 2.2.1 (Nullable feature enabled). When I write constructor of the class as following code, I got error as following image shows. Please help me to resolve this.
[image]

```
class FlavorBanner extends StatelessWidget {
  final Widget child ;
  late BannerConfig bannerConfig;
  FlavorBanner({@required this.child});

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the new keyword `required` instead of `@required`, which says the property is mandatory.

```
class FlavorBanner extends StatelessWidget {
  final Widget child;
  late BannerConfig bannerConfig;
  FlavorBanner({
    required this.child,
  });
}
```